# How do we accelerate animation if we are using images in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation

I have series of images for animation, say Image 1 to 1000.

I plan to show these images in a sequence at uniform rate to show animation.

I want to know if there is a way by which I can accelerate the animation? 
Can I accelerate the rate of showing images?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GIF` images to play animation. Playing GIF files with OpenGLES is the good practice and I believe it is the best way to play animation.

Follow the Git Link: https://github.com/jamesu/glgif

:)

Answer (score 0):

There is so many way but simplest way is to Pass image array to `UIImageView` property `animationImages`. then call `start Animating`to start the animation and `stopAnimating` method of `UIImageView` to stop the animation.

UIImageView also has the property `animationDuration` which allow to set the duration for every Images.

you can also render Images using OpenGL which is much faster compare to UIImageView. because OpenGL use the GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of how to animate. What I am looking for is way to accelerate the speed of animation.

Comment: then OpenGL looks best choice.. ;)

Comment: And how do we do that in OpenGL? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to skip frames of the animation. So, if you want to double the speed you will draw the 0,2,4,6 frames or 1,3,5,7 of the animation sequence. If you want to triple the speed you will draw 0,3,6,9 etc and so on. This is frame skipping :)