# How to animate image like this using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation

Please check [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/draw-hearts-happy-valentines/id419003288?mt=8) app:

Screenshot from that app is shown below:

[image]

Can you please let me know how to add an image on touch and have each image animated?

Comment: This question is a good question, just needs to be worded better. @meetpd wants to know how to add an image on touch and have each image animated, like in the app he included as an example.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to say. Rightly put by WrightsCS.

Comment: What is problem in using your previous question's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652471/how-do-we-accelerate-animation-if-we-are-using-images-in-iphone-sdk  Just give Click event on that image. it will be quite good instead on managing images...

Comment: Thanks Dhiren. I will check. Really appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **iOS 5**, you can use a sequence of images. First you will need to add a new category method:

### Category

```
@interface UIImage (WrightsCS)
+(UIImage*)animatedImageWithImages:(NSArray*)images duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
@end
```

### Example

```
+(UIImage*)loadingImage
{
    NSArray *animationFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading01.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading02.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading03.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading04.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading05.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading06.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading07.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading08.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading09.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading10.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading11.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading12.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading13.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading14.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading15.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading16.png"],
                                nil];
    return [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:animationFrames duration:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that this will be used to animate one image. How will be manage all the images that are generated when we click on the screen?

Comment: This probably works the same way, they may be adding a random image on each touch event.